# Cannot find "Custom Settings" in Org Browser (Visual Studio Code, SFDX)

Tags: salesforcedx, customsetting, sfdx-plugin, visualstudiocode

I creating a Custom Setting in a sandbox, called Global Settings (Global_Settings__c). I am trying to pull the Custom Setting into my SFDX project via Visual Studio Code, but "Custom Settings" does not appear in the Org Browser as a component type.

Using the Org Browser GUI, how can I find my Custom Setting in Visual Studio Code?

[image]

Comment: custom settings and custom metadata can be found in custom objects

Answer (score 1):

From the Org Browser (Salesforce Cloud Icon in the bar on the left panel), open the "Custom Objects" and look for the name of your Custom Setting. You'll find it there.